# H2O Deep Water with Docker Container Template -> Flow UI not accesible

Tags: docker, deep-learning, h2o

I started the Deep Water Docker container (CPU mode) on my Mac as described in the docs (https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater/blob/master/README.md):

docker run -it --rm -p 54321:54321 -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD:/host opsh2oai/h2o-deepwater-cpu

It starts correctly and without errors, but I cannot access the H2O UI at http://172.17.0.2:54321 ...

There is also a hint in the logs:
If you have trouble connecting, try SSH tunneling from your local machine 1. Open a terminal and run 'ssh -L 55555:localhost:54321 root@172.17.0.2'
2. Point your browser to http://localhost:55555

But this is also not working...

I use Docker CE Version 17.06.0-ce-mac19.

Any ideas what to do?

Here are the complete logs of starting H2O:

[image]

Comment: As side note: The AWS Image of same documentation does also not work: I did a "Docker pull", then starting the container brings: nvidia-docker | 2017/08/03 12:33:13 Error: nvml: Driver/library version mismatch

Answer (score 1):

When you have started the docker image you have to start H2O manually. You do that with

java -jar /opt/h2o.jar &

For more info on this, please see https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-docker-image

In the side note: Please post the log, I can't tell what went wrong from this. It's possible that your Nvidia driver is too old.

Comment: I did start H2O. As described in the docs. Also, please note that I use the CPU-only Docker Image as I want to run it on my Mac. What logs do I need to check / share?

Comment: For logs I mean what's printed on the screen when you run the commands. When you do `java ... &` it outputs its log on the screen. If you could post that we can figure out what went wrong. It's hard to tell with this little information about what you do. Note that to access h2o you go to http://localhost:54321 on the machine where you run docker from.

Comment: Added the logs to the post... I think there is no issue with starting H2O. Looks all good to me? I also do not use localhost for accessing the Flow UI in the browser. Maybe there is some wrong (security) configuration in the H2O Docker template so that I cannot access it?

Comment: From the outside of the docker image, the url will be http://localhost:54321 The IP address 172.... is only inside the docker. The -p flag makes the port available on the machine outside of docker.

Comment: Wow. That simple solution for my problem... :-) Thanks a lot.